# Converting on input int to string & finding correct number

Tags: java, string, int

I am trying to convert the input of a Int directly to a String.
I am also trying to make it so the program will find the correct number in a credit card sequence to make it correct.

For example if I input a incorrect credit card number, the program finds a way to change the numbers so it becomes correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input a credit card number to validate");

    String cc = in.nextLine();

    validateCreditCardNumber(cc);
    String convertedCC = (cc);
}

private static void validateCreditCardNumber(String str) {

    int[] ints = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    for (int i = ints.length - 2; i >= 0; i = i - 2) {
        int j = ints[i];
        j = j * 2;
        if (j > 9) {
            j = j % 10 + 1;
        }
        ints[i] = j;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        sum += ints[i];
    }
    if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println(str + " is a valid credit card number");
    } else {
        System.out.println(str + " is an invalid credit card number");
    }
}
```

That is all my code, but what i am trying to fix is when I initialize cc, i can convert to a string to be later used.

My issues:
int to string has been fixed,
converting to correct CC number has not been fixed.

Comment: You've *mistype*d the tags, my friend. Java and Javascript are not the same language, in the same way that Austria and Australia are not the same country.

Comment: You are already converting an integer to a string twice in your code. What's the trouble?

Comment: Why are you reading it as int then if you want it to be string? To get data as string use `next()` instead of `nextInt()`.

Comment: Exactly what integer value should the string "credit card numbers" be?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just get it as a string directly?

```
String cc = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code instead of *int cc = in.nextInt();*

**String cc = in.next();**

Answer (score 0):

You never use the int version of the scanned input. Instead of making cc an int then converting to a string, just initially make it a string... something like this:

`String cc = in.nextLine();`